# Changing items in DataGrid. Is this the right way?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a DataGrid binded to an ObservableCollection, and i'm sure the way i use to update the items in that collection is not the right way.
I've been having problems to make the DataGrid refresh. If i modify an item directly, the DataGrid doesn't refresh until i click another cell. I can see the NotifyPropertyChanged is being hit in "Details" and "_Detail", but the UI just doesn't refresh. After trying a lot of things, i found a workaround: I remove the previous one, and add the new item.
Thing is i wan't to do it the right way. So...which one is?

C#

```
public class AsientoDetallesViewModel : ViewModelBase, IInteractionRequestAware, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Details> details;
    public ObservableCollection<Details> Details
    {
        get => details;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref details, value, nameof(Details));
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Details));
        }
    }

    private Detail _detail;
    public Detail _Detail
    {
        get => _detail;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _detail, value, nameof(_Detail));
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(_Detail));
        }
    }

    private void UpdateRow()
    {
        var itemUpdated = _Detail;
        itemUpdated.Account.Name = "some name";
        itemUpdated.Account.Name2 = "another name";

        //the workaround
        Detalles.Remove(itemUpdated);
        Detalles.Add(itemUpdated);
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Details, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding _Details, Mode=TwoWay}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Binding Path=Account.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0" ></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Account.Name2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0, 3, 0, 0"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
         </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Does the `Account` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? It should.

Comment: No. It doesn't. "Detail" it's a POCO. Does it matter? Or there is no problem with INotifyPropertyChanged in POCO classes?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether `AsientoDetallesViewModel` or `Detail` implement the interface since it's an `Account` that you bind to. See my answer.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say "Account"

Comment: `Account` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Ok then. I'll post the results.

Answer (score 0):

It is the object returned from the `Account` property of the `Detail` class that must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notifications for the `TextBlocks` bound to the `Name` and `Name2` properties to get refreshed.

It doesn't matter whether `AsientoDetallesViewModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` since you are not binding to a property of this class.